# CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED and FacebookOperationCanceledException

Tags: android, facebook

Using the Android Facebook SDK 3.5, I have constant login problems: I receive `CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED` with `FacebookOperationCanceledException`. I know there are about a million `CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED` questions on SO but this one is different. **Please, no answers about "are your key hashes OK? Is it out of sandbox? Is the app id OK?", because they are. :-)** I tell you why I know they are:

If I disable SSO, I can log in using the more complicated, non-SSO approach. From that moment on, even if SSO is enabled again, it starts to work and there are no `CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED` answers later. *Same user, same keys, same app, same id, everything is the same.* Non-SSO login is only needed once and then everything returns to normal. Not a single isolated case, I could reproduce it consistently with a couple of different accounts.

`FacebookOperationCanceledException` is received in spite of the user authorizing the access. The proper permissions are asked for (actually, a single `publish_stream`, nothing more), the authorization dialog is all right, I press OK, not Cancel, still I get that exception.

The code is straight from the tutorial. Some relevant parts for reference:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
  if (state.isOpened()) {
    shareButton.setEnabled(true);
    if (pendingPublishReauthorization && state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
      pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
      publishStory();
    }
  }
  else if (state.isClosed())
    shareButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

...

```
final LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setPublishPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
```

...

```
uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, new Session.StatusCallback() {
  @Override
  public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
  }
});
```

...

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
  if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()))
    onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
  uiHelper.onResume();
}
```

Comment: where you able to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem here, did you solve it please ??

Comment: Not yet, it was put aside but I'll need to revisit that code in the future.

Comment: @Gábor I too have faced the same problem, I have managed to fix it by turning off sandbox mode. Sandbox mode allows only developers to login, if any other user it will return the status CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED

Comment: Finally, I moved on to the Share Dialog that provides a different workflow, partly simpler and partly more complicated because it can achieve much more. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog.

You can also have a Feed Dialog with different actions.

Comment: The share dialog is much more easier, but using share dialog prevent adding any caption so that what you can share is more limited.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - I was getting `CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED` with `com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException: User canceled operation` and I definitely wasn't canceling the operation.

After a good 7-8 hours of toying with every line of my application code, I noticed that this was set on my activity in my manifest. Removing it solved it.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

**OR another option to try**

It worked after I created an explicit app, SessionLoginSample, at developer.facebook.com. I copied the app id into the Android manifest, etc. and it worked. In other words, the Sample App configuration described in Facebook's Getting Started guide failed.

Comment: link to manifest.xml here: https://github.com/FocusBluetooth/focus-bluetooth-android/blob/master/facebook-android-sdk-3.0/samples/SessionLoginSample/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I think adding 'singleInstance' do make it return CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, but in this case, there is no such element in manifest.